# Use MASM to compile bootloader

Tags: assembly, masm, boot, bootloader, osdev

I am currently trying to learn how to code a bootloader and I have had one question for quite some time:

MASM creates object files by default.
Can I somehow get it to produce the simple binary format used for EFI etc? I see that the VeraCrypt Bootloader was made with NASM. Intel CPUs start in a legacy mode and need to be switched to long mode.

So, should I assume that I should assemble for 16 bit before switching the CPU into *LONG* mode?

Comment: If you're not assembling for (U)EFI, yes, your first step would be assembling for 16-bit BIOS compatibility code and then [set up LONG mode](https://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode).

Comment: EFI uses PECOFF format executables, so you can just Microsoft's linker with the `/SUBSYSTEM:EFI_APPLICATION` option.  For legacy BIOS booting you're out of luck with modern Microsoft tools.  If you can find it, you can use the old Microsoft segmented linker that creates 16-bit executables, including .COM files which are just plain binaries.

Comment: So the COM files can also be used as a bootloader?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - COM files - yes, they can be used for classic boot loaders. Creating a .COM program uses "tiny" model with Microsoft tool set.

Comment: COM files are loaded by MS-DOS at offset 100h within some segment so they're normally assembled with an ORG of 100h to match.  Legacy bootsectors load at 07C0:0000 and either use an ORG of 0 or ORG 7c00h depending on how they're written.  You might want to look through the bootloader tag to see more information on how to write bootsectors.